# How to define grok filtering?

Tags: java, logstash, microservices, kibana, elastic-stack

How can I define grok filtering pattern for below sample log message which is displayed in Kibana? I already defined more pattern but get `_grokparsefailure`

```
2018-12-10  14:50:01,497  [traceID : 46072cedb98568e3  spanID: 46072cedb98568e3 parent: ] service : networkService  [XNIO-2 task-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:3209}] to 192.168.0.207:27017
```

Here is my (WGSSAMINTHA) attempted solution.

```
filter { 
  grok { 
    match => { 
      "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{WORD:service} 
                    %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:duration}" 
    } 
    remove_field => [ "_type:doc", 
                      "_index:archisoft-log-all", 
                      "_score: dev" ] 
  } 
}
```

Comment: WGSSAMINTHA, what do you want to extract as information from the log? In the meantime, to help you, you can use the [grok debugger](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match), which is a great resources for writing patterns and the [basic grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

Comment: @StephenC Where did get you it from? I didn't see it in the original question. (I was surprised to see a high rep user do something like this and I thought it was a mistake.)

Comment: It was in a comment.

Comment: @StephenC Ok. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

This grok pattern `"%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{WORD:service} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:duration}"` is wrong to parse the provided log line. A grok pattern will be translated in a regex against which the log line will be matched; if the regex doesn't match the log line, you'd get the `_grokparsefailure`. It means that the order of the base patterns is important.

Since you didn't said what information you wanted from the log line, I extracted some parts that seemed important:

```
  grok { 
    match => { 
      "message" => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}  \[traceID \: %{DATA:traceID}  spanID\: %{DATA:spanID} parent\: %{DATA:parent}\] service \: %{WORD:service}  \[%{DATA:thread}\] %{DATA:message}$"
    }
  }
```

This will extract those values:

```
parent  
spanID      46072cedb98568e3
service     networkService
thread      XNIO-2·task-1
date        2018-12-10·14:50:01,497
message     org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:3209}] to 192.168.0.207:27017
traceID     46072cedb98568e3
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, But still got same issue. Actually i want to search logs in kibana quickly by formatting logs message.

Comment: @WGSSAMINTHA To format the log message, you'll have to put the part in fields (with grok for example), then to format, you'd use the [format option of the plain codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-plain.html#plugins-codecs-plain-format) on your output.